# value of a function that takes an argument which is itself a function

Tags: function, matlab

I am trying a simple function as follows:

```
function out=Y_T(f,a,b)
  Y_T=f(a)-f(b)
end
```

f is an argument which is a function itself. For example f=x^4+3. The function T_Y should evaluate the values of f in 'a' and 'b' and subtract them. But when i try to use this function for example T_Y(x^4+3,5,2) i face with an error: Index exceeds matrix dimension. How can i fix it? Any tips will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this a matlab question? .... if it is, then why are you asking it here? .... note: read the error text .... why do you think that it relates to functions?

Comment: the syntax should be something like fun(@fun_arg, arg1, ..., argn), don't forget the '@' character here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply have your syntax wrong - as written, you're passing the numeric value `x^4 + 3` into `Y_T`. I *think* what you need is:

```
Y_T(@(x) x^4 + 3, 5, 2)
```

This defines an [anonymous function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and passes it in to `Y_T`.

Your definition of `Y_T` is slightly wrong too - you need to assign the result to `out`, like so:

```
function out=Y_T(f,a,b)
  out=f(a)-f(b)
end
```